# Detect Mac Application moved to trash folder using launch Agents

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, launchd

I want to run a script when my application moved into trash folder and I come to know that using launch agents its possible, I googled and made the plist but its not working or not calling the script..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.meet.anywhere</string>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/.Trash</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/eclit/Desktop/DeleteScript.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

launchd cannot run the applescript directly. You need to use the command line tool osascript to run the applescript. As such your ProgramArguments portion should look like the following. Also, there's no need for the KeepAlive section. It does nothing so I'd remove it.

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>/Users/eclit/Desktop/DeleteScript.scpt</string>
</array>
```

Comment: osascript is asking for permission, it this possible to get the permission before??

Comment: I am seeing now a problem that whenever any thing moves to trash my script is getting called, how can i make it specific about  when only my app moves into trash??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.meet.anywhere</string>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/.Trash/AppName.app</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>osascript</st
        <string>/Users/eclit/Desktop/DeleteScript.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```